# JSON Convert in C#

Tags: c#, json

How is it posible to convert this JSON-String into Strings and Ints to show in a label or contextmenu?

```
[{"pkID":"1","strName":"Prototyp","fkBoardType":"3","strLocation":"Johans Zimmer","datOperationStart":"2021-03-29 12:27:25","datLastConfig":"2021-04-26 12:00:06"},{"pkID":"5","strName":"TestBoard","fkBoardType":"3","strLocation":"Irgendwo","datOperationStart":"2021-05-05 09:04:01","datLastConfig":"2021-05-05 09:04:01"}]
```

The [] brackets are dificult for me, because the JSON object has no name. E.g.:

```
"Test":[{...},{...}]
```

Comment: Square braces -> collection object in C# (i.e. list, array, etc.)

Comment: @Johan, You have List (Array) of JSON, you can iterate (loop) and then each json element you can parse & extract value of key

Comment: Thanks @ShivamSeth. This helped a lot! I found another solution here: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df1d6c1b-349a-4f7f-9168-5bf01d320075/how-to-get-keyvalue-pair-from-json-jarray)

Answer (score 1):

You can map Json data to a corresponding class.

add this class

```
public class JsonData
{
   public int PkID { get; set; }
   public string StrName { get; set; }
   public int FkBoardType { get; set; }
   public string StrLocation { get; set; }
   public DateTime DatOperationStart { get; set; }
   public DateTime DatLastConfig { get; set; }
}
```

Then Deserialize

```
List<JsonData> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonData>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If no class then use dynamic

```
 string jsonString = @"{'pkID':'1','strName': 'Prototyp ', 'fkBoardType ': '3 ', 'strLocation ': 'Johans Zimmer ', 'datOperationStart ': '2021 - 03 - 29 12:27:25 ', 'datLastConfig ': '2021 - 04 - 26 12:00:06 '}";

var vCustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

[Dynamic Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs8WG.jpg)